# How to reduce runtime from linear to constant?

Tags: c, linked-list, big-o

lengthOfLinkedList() below counts the number of nodes in a linked list, but the runtime is linear which I do not want. How can I reduce it to a constant runtime function? Are there any library functions I can use?

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

struct list_struct {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
};

int lengthOfLinkedList(LIST *l) {
    NODE *n = l->front;
    int count = 0;
    while (n != NULL) {
        count++;
        n = n->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your list struct will need to keep track of the length. When a node is added, increase the count. Do the opposite for removal. Then it's simply `return l->size;`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve constant time size calculation with your current struct definition. Now, if you add a `size_t` member to the struct and use it to store the length, modifying it on any additions or deletions, you can access the length in constant time.

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
    size_t length;
} NODE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `head-node` `struct` accordingly.

For `int` value type the `list-node` remains same:

```c
typedef struct _node {
    int val;
    struct _node* next;
} listNode_t;
```

We alter the `head-node` to suit our needs:

```c
typedef struct {
    // add members as scenario demands
    int size; // updated after every insert/delete
    int min;  // updated/checked after every insert/delete/update
    int max;  // updated/checked after every insert/delete/update
    long sum; // updated after every insert/delete/update
    listNode_t* first; // to insert/delete from beginning (LIFO-Stack)
    listNode_t* last;  // to insert at the end (can't delete though)
} listHead_t;
```

Then you can get those values in `O(1)`, provided they're updated consistently.

```c
listHead_t* head;
...
int listLength = list_getSize (head);
int listMin = list_getMin (head);
int listMax = list_getMax (head);
long listSum = list_getSum (head);
float listAvg = list_getAverage (head);  // (float)sum/size

/* List Methods */
list_prefix (head, value);  // add value as the first node
list_suffix (head, value);  // add value as the last node
```

That makes `list_prefix()` like:

```c
...
#include <limits.h>
...
listHead_t* head = list_init_head ();
...
...
listHead_t* list_init_head () {
    listHead_t* head = malloc (sizeof(listHead_t));
    if (!head) {
        perror("list_init_head-malloc");
        exit (1);
    }
    head->size = head->sum = 0;
    head->first = head->last = NULL;
    head->min = INT_MAX;
    head->max = INT_MIN;
    return head;
}

int list_prefix (listHead_t* head, int val) {
    if (!head) return -1; // invalid call
    listNode_t* node = malloc (sizeof(listNode_t));
    if (!node) {
        perror("list_prefix-malloc");
        exit (1);
    }
    node->val = val;
    // update list-head stats
    ++head->size;
    head->sum += val;
    if (val < head->min) head->min = val;
    if (val > head->max) head->max = val;
    if (!head->first) {
        node->next = NULL;
        head->first = head->last = node;
    } else {
        node->next = head->first;
        head->first = node;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Little reason for member `sum` as a `long`.  Many implementations have the same range for `int` and `long`. `long long sum` or `intmax_t sum` make more sense for extended range.