# Calculate the sum, avg and nodes of a linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, average, insertion-sort

I have this linked list c program right here. It lets the user enter as many numbers as possible until 0 is entered. The list is then displayed and sorted numerically from smallest to biggest....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
} node;

node * insert(node *head, int num)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = num;

    if (head == NULL || head->data > num)
    {
        temp->ptr = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *current = head;
        while ((current->ptr != NULL) && !(num < current->ptr->data))

        {
            current = current->ptr;
        }

        temp->ptr = current->ptr;
        current->ptr = temp;
    }

    return head;
}

node * delete_if_less( node *head, int data )
{
    while ( head != NULL && head->data < data )
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->ptr;
        free( temp );
    }

    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        for ( node *current = head; current->ptr != NULL; )
        {
            if ( current->ptr->data < data )
            {
                node *temp = current->ptr;
                current->ptr = current->ptr->ptr;
                free( temp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void free_list(node *head) {
    node *prev = head;
    node *cur = head;
    while(cur) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = prev->ptr;
        free(prev);
    }
}

int main(){
    int num, min;
    node *head, *p;
    head = NULL;

    do {
        printf(": ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if(num) {
            head = insert(head, num);
            for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->ptr )
            {
                printf("%d ", p->data);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while(num);

    p = head;
    printf("\n:\n");

    while(p) {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->ptr;
    }
    free_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

My next step would be 1) calculating the sum of the numbers in the list 2) calculating how many numbers are in the list and finally 3) the arithmetic average of the numbers in the list. This is how it should look like...

```
: 1
1 
: 2
1 2
: 3
1 2 3 
: 1
1 1 2 3
: 5
1 1 2 3 5
: 0
1 1 2 3 5

total sum: 12
elements: 5
average: 2.4
```

My question is how do I make and calculate the sum, average and numbers of nodes of a linked list like this??

Comment: You can use a `head-node` structure like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71510100/835145)

Comment: You are already printing each value from the list, so why can't you sum up all the numbers? Instead of the `printf` you have to do `sum += p->data;` and for the count you can do `count++;` next to it.

Comment: `for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->ptr )` You already know how to iterate over the list. So what prevents you from using that to visit each node and do what you need (e.g. sum each node `data` value)?

Comment: A side note: you have the logic for traversing and printing the list at least twice in your code. Such code duplication almost always calls for extracting it into a separate function.

Comment: @SparKot Suggested alternative greatly increases the size of empty lists.  As linked-lists may be _very_ numerous is an application with many of them empty, the unnecessary heavy head node size can be a significant impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum:

```
int sum = 0;

for (p = head; p; p = p->ptr)
    sum += p->data;

return sum;
```

Average:

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;

for (p = head; p; p = p->ptr)
{
    sum += p->data;
    count++;
}

return sum / count;
```

Comment: where would this go?? Arent I redefining sum again?

Comment: @TahaHagar: You can put them wherever you want. Yes, if you put both samples in the same function, you'll need to remove one of the declarations. Also, you probably wouldn't use `return` in that case.